# Automatically add chat event to the community bulletin (or make it easier)

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, community-bulletin

When creating some Chat event on my site, I usually go to the Chat Room's info and there I schedule my event.

But, if I want the users to notice that, I also need to add it in the Community Bulletin. Manually.

There are some differences in the two tools:

The **Schedule Chat Event** has a *Description*, a *Date* and a *Duration*. The **Community Bulletin** is more or less the same, but as an addendum, we can *set an URL*, usually pointing to the Meta question that concerns that announcement on the Bulletin; and we can also decide when the announcement will be on the bulletin, *deciding the start and end date*.

Like I said, all of this is currently done manually. I honestly think that this double task could be one (given the technical aspect won't be a problem). My feature-request is to **automatically add the event in the Community Bulletin**.

I'm not sure if this is easy to add to the current tools, but although it's not a "fatal" error/bug, it would simplify the setting of new events.

Comment: I thought this already happened?

Comment: @NeilFein I expected it to happen the first time too, but nope, it doesn't. You have to do it manually.

Comment: Are you sure this doesn't happen for the same extremely brief period of time the System Message used to show up? Granted this would work better, but I think it shows the message all of 15 minutes before the event

Comment: @BenBrocka Yes, it shows in the System Message. But (1) that's too close to the event, I want to advertise it for a longer time (as others do), and (2) I can't use the SM for that, while I can use the CB for that. In any case, I'm not asking for something "new", but rather to make something that already exists easier to use (or automatic).

Comment: FWIW, this is *mostly* implemented - however, the bulletin event won't be added until about an hour before the chat event begins (same as the old system messages).

Comment: @Shog9 Ah thanks for letting me know. Are there plans for making it appear as soon as the event is added instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chat events used to be added to the community bulletin 1 hour before the event started.

This has been updated to (mostly) fulfill the feature request:

**All one-off (i.e., non-recurring) chat events are added to the community bulletin almost as soon as the event is created (they should appear within about 15 minutes of the chat event's creation).**

Note that this does not apply to any chat event that is set up as a recurring event. It becomes much more technically difficult to deal with recurring events, so we're declining to implement the request on those.

Answer (score 1):

Worth noting that chat events currently generate system messages:

[image: Example]

Where instead they should generate bulletin posts.

Comment: It has actually been said [in the comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138273/automatically-add-chat-event-to-the-community-bulletin-or-make-it-easier/166009#166009). :P